# electron Low Quality NativeImage toJPG

Tags: javascript, electron

im using web contents.capture() function to get screenshot from window but the quality of image is not satisfying 
heres the code

```
ipcRenderer.on('saved-file', (event, path) =>{
  if (path) {
    remote.BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow().webContents.[capturePage][1]((image)=>{
    scrImage = image.toJPEG(100);
    console.log(scrImage.toString());
    fs.writeFile(path, scrImage, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
      console.log(path);
    });

  });
```

[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uo8fq.jpg)

as you can see above the image Res is not good enough for our users;
in Electron DemoAPI quality of Capture image is the same.

is there any other ways to get better quality?

Comment: Can you explain what is not satisfying about the picture? Post an example

Comment: @Hschmale users claim its not good enough for their use cases

Comment: Is there a toPng method and a resize method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be really great to know why the quality is not satisfying for your users. It captured exactly the same image as it was painted on your `BrowserWindow`.

However [`NativeImage` API](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/native-image.md) provides you some ways to improve your image quality:

- You can convert to PNG
- You can resize the image
- You can use high-DPI images on high-DPI diplays

The following code creates an ~800 KB png as screenshot:

```js
const { BrowserWindow, app } = require('electron')
const fs = require('fs')

app.once('ready', () => {
  let win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1280, // win size affects captured image ofc
    height: 720
  })
  win.webContents.on('dom-ready', () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      win.capturePage( img => {
        var conv = img.resize({ // resize
          width: 2560,
          height: 1480,
          quality: 'best'
        }).toPNG(1.0) // to PNG
        fs.writeFile(__dirname + '/captured.png', conv, err => {
          if (err) console.log(err)
        });
      })
    }, 3000);
  })
  win.loadURL('http://github.com')
})
```